# How do I import firebase package into Thonny? Python Version 3.7.9

Tags: python, firebase, syntax-error, backend, thonny

When I try to import firebase in Thonny I constantly get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jackl\brhyu.py", line 1, in <module>
    import firebase
  File "C:\Users\jackl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\firebase\__init__.py", line 3
    from .async import process_pool
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas what's wrong? My code is literally just:

```
import firebase
```

I have tried commenting the ".async" part out which didn't work.

I have also tried replacing the code in the backend such as replacing

```
import atexit

from .async import process_pool
from firebase import *
```

with

```
import atexit
from .async import process_pool
from .multiprocess_pool import process_pool
from firebase import *
```

and then replacing

```
from .firebase_token_generator import FirebaseTokenGenerator
from .decorators import http_connection

from .async import process_pool
from .jsonutil import JSONEncoder

__all__ = ['FirebaseAuthentication', 'FirebaseApplication']
```

with

```
import json

from .firebase_token_generator import FirebaseTokenGenerator
from .decorators import http_connection

from .async import process_pool
from .multiprocess_pool import process_pool
from .jsonutil import JSONEncoder
```

I'm completely stumped...

Any help is greatly appreciated, I need this for a ***big exam***

Comment: Try using IDLE (`sudo apt install idle3`), Thonny is weird sometimes when importing packages.

Comment: Even that is giving me a syntax error --

sudo apt install idle3
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax